# Python: change variable vs. change list of variable inside a function

Tags: python-3.x

I need a counter variable `k` that needs to be defined outside the function where it is updated (this is because I want define a recursive function). I found out that I can only do this if `k` is an element of a list:

```
def g(k):
    k +=1
    return 
​
def f():
    k = 0
    g(k)
    return k
​
f()
0
```

vs.

```
def g(k):
    k[0] +=1
    return

def f():
    k = [0]
    g(k)
    return k[0]
f()
1
```

Why is this? Is there a better way of doing this?

Below I show the real code:

```
def coins(n, m_25, m_10, m_5, m_1, m_tot, count):

    if m_tot == n:
        count[0] +=1
        return

    if m_tot > n:
        return

    coins(n, m_25+1, m_10, m_5, m_1, m_tot+25, count)
    coins(n, m_25, m_10+1, m_5, m_1, m_tot+10, count)
    coins(n, m_25, m_10, m_5+1, m_1, m_tot+5, count)
    coins(n, m_25, m_10, m_5, m_1+1, m_tot+1, count)

def get_coins(n, m_25, m_10, m_5, m_1, m_tot):
    count = [0]
    coins(n, m_25, m_10, m_5, m_1, m_tot, count)
    return count[0]
```

Comment: Is the final counter the only thing you're interested in returning?

Comment: @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica yes.

Comment: " need a counter variable k that needs to be defined outside the function where it is updated (this is because I want define a recursive function)" You don't have to do it that way because it is recurisve...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how can initialize the value of the counter inside a recursive function? As far as I can see, its value would be set to 0 with each recursive call, which I don't want.

Comment: @Mencia you use an accumulator argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP says they're only interested in returning the counter, we can set the recursive function to return the current counter and increment it by 1 every time it calls itself.

**Edit**: Changed the default count to 1 instead of 0 since (logically) the first time the function is called.. the counter should be set to 1.

A small sample would look like:

```py
def func(x, count=1):
    if x >= 10: # Example base case
        return count
    return func(x+1, count+1)

print(f"Counter result = {func(-4)}")
# >> 15
```

Or, applied to the OP's actual code: (disclaimer: I don't really know what your code is supposed to do so you may need to slightly change the logic regarding when count is incremented. You also never use `m_25`, `m_10`, `m_5`, or `m_1` in your code so I really have no idea what this function is supposed to do)

```py
def coins(n, m_25, m_10, m_5, m_1, m_tot, count=1):
    if m_tot == n:
        count +=1
        return count
    if m_tot > n:
        return count
    count = coins(n, m_25+1, m_10, m_5, m_1, m_tot+25, count)
    count = coins(n, m_25, m_10+1, m_5, m_1, m_tot+10, count)
    count = coins(n, m_25, m_10, m_5+1, m_1, m_tot+5, count)
    count = coins(n, m_25, m_10, m_5, m_1+1, m_tot+1, count)
    return count

def get_coins(n, m_25, m_10, m_5, m_1, m_tot):
    return coins(n, m_25, m_10, m_5, m_1, m_tot)

print(f"Coins: {get_coins(10, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2)}") 
# >> 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do use m_25 ... m_1 in the code as I change their value on the recursive calls. I am trying to count the number of ways to get n cents using coins of 25, 10, 5 and 1 cents. My code doesn't give the right answer because it considers 5+1 and 1+5 as two different combinations.

Comment: You do use them as arguments to your recursive call, but you don't do anything with them. You could delete all references of `m_25`, `m_10`, `m_5`, and `m_1` and the result would still be the same. Is `m_tot` supposed to be the sum of all your coins? i.e. should `m_tot` equal `m_25*25 + m_10*10 + …`?

Answer (score 1):

How about returning the value to the calling function like this?

```
def g(k):
    return k + 1

def f():
    k = 0
    return g(k)


print(f())
```

The reason your list works, is because lists are mutable data structure which is passed to `g`. Contrary to this, integers are immutable, so when you assign to the same name as an existing integer of the same scope, a new integer is created in memory and assigned to that name.

Comment: You are right when you say integers aren't mutable, however a copy is *not* passed to `g`. The int object being passed *is* the original integer (you can check this yourself by checking `id(k)` in each function). Instead, what's really happening when you say `x += 1` is you are creating a *new* integer on the right hand side (equal to `x+1`) and then storing that as the value for `x` in the current namespace

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your solution, doesn't really work for me, see my edit above.

Comment: Mutable objects **are not passed by reference** in Python. Python uses a *single evaluation strategy regardless of the type of object being passed*, and it is *neither call by reference nor call by value*.